# Can Dating Be Used In Non-Romantic Situations?

Tags: word-usage, dates

Would such sentence make sense?

"Tonight is our date night with mom."

Comment: When I say,"I have a date night with Mom", it has a totally different meaning.

Comment: @Cascabel thanks for the response. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If I elaborate any more, I will be sharing _intimate_ details...There is also the so-called "play-date" for children.

Comment: So going out with mom to watch movies or eat at a restaurant should never ever be called as "date" under socially acceptable circumstances?

Comment: No, it is just that many old married people would have a different interpretation of "_date night_", and use in it in a private context. In ODO, it is listed as a "[pre-arranged date for established married couples](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/date_night)". Whether it is romantic or not depends on the couple, I guess.

Comment: The verb _to date_ can be used in non-romantic situations, yes. For example, we date archaeological artefacts (or more commonly, the artefacts _are dated_ to a certain period, in the passive). The word _date night_ contains the **noun** _date_, not the verb. The noun _date_ can of course also be used in non-romantic situations (the date today is 6 March, and I like to eat dates), but using the noun _date night_ in non-romantic situations would be highly unusual. You can say that you have a date with non-romantic things (your school books, for instance), but that doesn’t make it a date night.

Comment: Thanks @JanusBahsJacquet. So it's the "night" word changing the context in this case? How about I say, "I'm dating mom for lunch today."?

Comment: No, that’s even worse. “I’m dating X” means that you are romantically involved with them over a longer period of time (or that’s you’re archaeologically dating it using carbon-dating or similar methods—you wouldn’t normally do that to your mother, though). Going on a date with someone can be a single occasion; dating someone is a process. You could say, “I have a lunch date with mom today”, that works.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  thanks again. Can you give me a sentence with "date" word to use in this context; mom takes her 1 year old baby out to the playground.

Comment: No, you wouldn’t use _date_ to describe that. A date is something that is pre-arranged between two parties who meet in a certain place. If the kid is going over to a friend’s house and the parents have agreed on this beforehand, it’s a _play-date_ (as Cascabel said above), but just taking your child to the park is not a date.

Comment: Definitely a 'date' need not be romantic (e.g. play-date).  But... romantic overtones cling tight and you'd need to be pretty po-faced not to acknowledge this when confirming with someone you are not 'seeing' that you have a 'date' ;-)

Comment: So to sum up, to remove the romantic meaning from "date", one needs to add "having a" prefix to "date". Is that right?

Comment: In that case I can also say "I have a date with mom at the local tonight.". Is that correct? @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: How about using "mother-son date" in this circumstance? How would you use it in a sentence?

Comment: Listen; In spite of the answers below to the contrary, if you are not a native speaker you should probably avoid using the word _except_ in a romantic context _unless_ it is in a recognized extended usage like "play-date", "date with destiny", or "date" an archeological/paleontological artefact. The word is too charged in meaning, and a screw-up here can very easily become unintentionally humourous. "Have" a date, "go on" a date, etc, usually have pretty much the same meaning. And that´s about all I got to say about that.

Comment: @Cascabel I don't think the purpose of English SE should be advising non-native speakers to stop using words with multiple meanings.

Comment: a whimsical thought: what about carbon dating? This just could be the evening when a group of archaeologists are testing their mother to see how old she is...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet what about this advertisement? It says: Mother Son Date Night; Moms and their sons (age 4+) can step out in style for a special evening they’ll never forget! https://www.heparks.org/event/mother-son-date-night-2/

Comment: I'll just accept Gnawme's answer as it's pretty clear. Thanks for all the participants joined to this conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A *[date](http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/date)* is simply:

> **5a**: an appointment or engagement usually for a specified time
>
> [has a *date* with his lawyer to discuss the sale of a house]

Of course, it's usually:

> a social engagement between two persons that often has a romantic character

But not exclusively.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would that be right to generalise the situation like following? To remove the romantic meaning from "date", one needs to add "having a" prefix to "date".

Comment: If I understand your question, yes. Saying _"I have a date with my lawyer._" is quite different than saying, _"I'm dating my lawyer._"

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a date is just a date-- no commitment, no obligation, just sort of getting to know that person in a romantic capacity. You do not do that with your mom.

"Dating" means that it is someone you are "seeing" regularly but may not be serious with yet. "We're dating" sounds way too casual for someone that you are in a serious relationship with.